# how to match to the correct action method through routes in mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am so puzzled that I am failed to correctly title this question.
Here's my problem. Following are the routes in my application.

```
//"list/author" => list by author
routes.MapRoute("ListByAuthor",
       "list/{author}",
        new { controller = "MyCtrl", action = "MyAction" });

//"list/tag" => list by tag
routes.MapRoute("ListBytag",
       "list/{tag}",
        new { controller = "MyCtrl", action = "MyACtion" });

//default
routes.MapRoute("Default",
       "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "MyCtrl", action = "MyAction", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

I am generating the links on the view by providing **RouteName** i.e **ListByAuthor**, **ListByTag** and **Default**. I have two issues:-

1. Matching the inbound url to the appropriate action method is not happening.
   Every request is handled by the first route `ListByAuthor`. ***For example, when I click on the tag, address bar shows the correct url format i.e `domain/list/tag` but by debugging I find out that the `tag` value is assigned to `author` argument.***
2. While clicking on other link the ambient value keeps hanging with the url. Consequently other links brake down and starts biting me. For instance when I click on author link, tag link becomes `domain/list/tag?author`. One of the solution on the site suggest passing `String.Empty` in the route value but it doesn't work. However if I changed the routes as following

   ```
   //"list/author" => list by author
   routes.MapRoute("ListByAuthor",
      "list/{author}",
       new { controller = "MyCtrl", action = "MyAction", tag = "" }); //providing empty value to tag parameter in route
   ```

It works however providing default value explicitly in the routes is a lot of work. Plz suggest me some answer. I am struggling with the routes. Support me to win this war ;). thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

i'm not expert, but i think that the reason is because the route that you have are the same,
example

yourdomain.com/list/authorxm, will match the first route

yourdomain.com/list/tagx, will match as well

because {author} and {tag} are just the parameter

try with this:

```
    //"list/author" => list by author
   routes.MapRoute("ListByAuthor",
   "list/ByAuthor/{author}",
    new { controller = "MyCtrl", action = "MyActionByAuthor" });

    //"list/tag" => list by tag
     routes.MapRoute("ListBytag",
   "list/ByTag/{tag}",
    new { controller = "MyCtrl", action = "MyACtionByTag" });

    //default
     routes.MapRoute("Default",
   "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "MyCtrl", action = "MyAction", id = UrlParameter.Optional })
```